# Properly doing relative imports in python

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

I always have the same problem and I finally want to get rid of it. My folder structure looks like this

```
project
├── scipts
│   └── folder
│       └── file.py
└── submodules
    └── lab_devices
        └── optical_devices
            └── __init__.py
            └── powermeter_driver.py
```

I now want to include the `powermeter_driver.py` in `file.py`. So what I do in the `file.py` is:

```
from submodules.lab_devices.optical_devices.powermeter_driver import PowermeterDriver
```

but this gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodules'`. I don't want to use

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../submodules')
```

Is there an easy workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imports will be resolved correctly if you run the script in the correct way, which is from the parent directory and using the `-m` switch. So you should cd in the `parent` folder, add `__init__.py` files as in:

```
project
├── scripts
    └── __init__.py
│   └── folder
        └── __init__.py
│       └── file.py
└── submodules
    └── __init__.py
    └── lab_devices
        └── __init__.py
        └── optical_devices
            └── __init__.py
            └── powermeter_driver.py
```

so that python knows these are packages then run

```
python -m scripts.folder.file # note no .py
```

In file.py you can then use the absolute import as you are cause `submodules` will be detected as a package. You should indeed avoid hacking the `sys.path` by all means.